# STL/CLR Library uses IComparable to implement == operator and throws NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, c++, .net, cliext

I had a .NET class which was not implementing `IComparable` interface.
After I implemented `IComparable` interface on this class some c++ code using my class changed it's behavior unexpectedly. Now it throws a `NullReferenceException`

```
DWORD UnitsAdapter::GetUnitNames([Out]array<MyClass^>^% unitNames)
{

  ...

  unitNames = gcnew array<MyClass^>(10);

  DWORD dwRet = BUMC_OK;
  for (int i = 0; i < unitNames->Length; ++i)
  {
    unitNames[i] = nullptr;
    unitNames[i] = CoCliUnitsHelper::getUnitName(unitIds[i]);

    if (nullptr == unitNames[i])
      dwRet = BUMC_NOT_COMPLETE;
  }

  return dwRet;
```

}

**The problem was in the line `if (nullptr == unitNames[i])` which started using `IComparable` implementation to perform `==` operation!**

The reason was a template from `cliext` utility header file.

```
//
// System::IComparable TEMPLATE COMPARISONS
//
template<typename _Value_t>
    bool operator==(System::IComparable<_Value_t>^ _Left,
        System::IComparable<_Value_t>^ _Right)
    {   // test if _Left == _Right
    return (_Left->CompareTo(_Right) == 0);
    }
```

***Question 1:*** I am not a c++ expert, so can someone explain me why this implementation does not perform a null check on `_Left` before calling `CompareTo()` method ? According to [MSDN Guidelines for Overloading Equals() and Operator ==](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) null checks must be done prior of doing anything inside `==` operator.

```
 ...
 // If both are null, or both are same instance, return true.
 if (System.Object.ReferenceEquals(a, b))
 {
        return true;
 }

 // If one is null, but not both, return false.
 if (((object)a == null) || ((object)b == null))
 {
        return false;
 }
 ...
```

***Question 2:*** Is there probably some flaw in usage which leads to such an unpredictable behavior?

Comment: Not an answer, but holly crab, what I nightmare of a language... Microsoft knows how to mess things up, for sure.

Comment: The STL/CLR library is very problematic.  It was two years late and suffers from severe perf problems.  It is widely ignored, best you do the same.  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24206/A-look-at-STL-CLR-performance-for-linear-container

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> so can someone explain me why this implementation does not perform a null check on _Left before calling CompareTo() method

Because whoever wrote it neglected to check for nulls.

> Is there probably some flaw in usage which leads to such an unpredictable behavior?

Well, comparing a null pointer to something is probably an edge case, but I certainly wouldn't call it a "flaw".  The implementation of `==` is incorrect.

To workaround this issue, you could reverse your equality check and/or check for `null`:

```
if (unitNames[i] == nullptr)
  dwRet = BUMC_NOT_COMPLETE;
```

Comment: The "WHOEVER" is [Microsoft STL/CLR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385954.aspx) :)

Comment: The "WHOEVER" is the person (or people) at Microsoft that wrote the template(s).  They're not infallible just because they work at MS.  Feel free to file it as a bug with MS.